# Multivariable calculus, stuck finding potential functions?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I am having a hard time with a question on my calc 3 hw. Find a potential function for $F(x, y, z) = \langle y + z, x + z, x + y\rangle$ on $\Bbb R^3$. I've determined it is conservative.

Comment: [MathInsight](http://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_find_potential_3d) does a great job at explaining multivariable calculus topics, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} = \mathit{F}_0$$
Integrate that with respect of $x$. You should get
$$ \phi_0 = U(x, y, z) + C(y, z)$$
where $U, C$ are functions. Differentiate with respect of $y$:
$$ \mathit{F}_1 = \phi_1 = \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial y}$$
Now move $\partial U/\partial y$ to the left and integrate with respect of $y$. You will get the antiderivative after repeating this process for $z$.